American pronunciation disparity between Longman and Cambridge dictionary for the word "character"
I found that there are many disparities between different dictionaries especially for American pronunciation.
for example the word "character" pronunciation in Longman is /ˈkærəktər/ and in Cambridge it is  /ˈker.ək.tɚ/.
I also checked Youglish and I guess I can hear both sounds in different videos.
This is the case also in words like parallel and parenthesis.
Is it regional variations?
Which one is the standard reference pronunciation?

Hi, does this answer your question? How are 'marry', 'merry', and 'Mary' pronounced differently?

Why do you think there's some standard reference pronunciation?

Welcome to ELU. There simply is no “standard reference pronunciation,” no single ideal to which anyone—let alone everyone—must aspire.

…and now that I think of it, no individual speaker always uses any single pronunciation in every circumstance.

I’m voting to close this question because it is posited upon there being a standard pronunciation.

@Greybeard In this case there's a very specific reason for the discrepancy between dictionaries, and properly explaining it would be quite valuable!

@tchrist The first part of the question ("Is it regional variations?") is surely answerable. Voting to reopen.

@alphabet I'm not altogether sure whether saying Cambridge with the /e/ of came or with the /æ/ of cam-shaft is strictly regional. :)

@alphabet - OK, I'll bite - what's this reason? The rhotic 'r''? As an aside the OED gives, for the verb and noun, BRITISH ENGLISH /ˈkarᵻktə/ KARR-uhk-tuh; U.S. ENGLISH /ˈkɛr(ə)ktər/ KAIR-uhk-tuhr

@Greybeard There are at least three and quite possibly four or more pronunciations of that word's stressed vowel in America. It's silly to pretend there's just one.

@tchrist doubtless - I said as much in my comment suggesting closing this post.

@tchrist: Does anybody pronounce character with the vowel of Mary, assuming that they pronounce Mary, marry, and merry all differently. If not, then I would say that there are only two pronunciations of the stressed vowel in character in AmE. (Unless you're talking about phones and not phonemes. which muddies everything up.)

@PaulTanenbaum and greybeard and tchrist There are loads of words for which there's a "standard" pronunciation in the same way that there's "standard" grammar, which just means there's a pronunciation or some grammatical form which is part of the prestige dialect (nothing that ascribes any special status to the standard/bog-standard dialect in question).

@PeterShor In “Quality of American English front vowels before /r/” (2003) Clark and Hillenbrand show that “/e/ and /ε/ are not contrastive before /r/ .. and the mid front vowel (in bear and hair) was intermediate between /e/ and /ε/, but closer to /e/”. Most Americans—and certainly ‘General’ American—will neutralize any tense–lax distinction before /r/ and will perceive those vowels to be only tense monophthongal phonemes even when other phones may happen to be produced in that position by some speakers.

@Araucaria-Him  Here’s that Clark and Hillenbrand reference I just mentioned to Peter Shor. We cannot in general trust dictionaries to tell us how people pronounce things, especially British Dictionaries using British symbols for American English where these do not apply.

@tchrist: The vowels in merry, Mary, and marry are all still different in New York City. Some dictionaries, like American Heritage, like to give different phonemic notations as long as a significant percentage of Americans distinguish the phonemes. For example, it was only in 2005 that they stopped distinguishing horse and hoarse, words which nearly all Americans pronounced the smae at the time. And I suspect you'd object strongly if somebody published an American dictionary that didn't distinguish the vowels in cot and caught, even if they're the same in California.

In North American English, /ær/ is largely merged with /ɛr/ (= /er/ in the dictionaries' notation). According to the 2003 Harvard Dialect Survey, 57% of Americans merge all of Mary/merry/marry.
But when it comes to pronunciation, dictionaries aimed at non-native speakers of English try to reduce the amount of information their targeted readership needs to learn. As Michael Ashby, the phonetics editor of the sixth edition of the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, put it:

[The system adopted by the dictionary] has a number of features which are strictly speaking redundant from an American point of view (for instance, it uses length marks). The intention is that the redundant features can be overlooked by a user interested only in American pronunciation, but they serve the important function of permitting a single transcription to do for both accents in many cases. Thus seat is /siːt/ and need not be transcribed /siːt; US sit/.

Any learner of English needs to learn the difference between /æ/ and /e/ (= /ɛ/), as in bad and bed. But no American or Canadian will have trouble understanding you just because you pronounce marry with /æ/. So a learner's dictionary may choose not to teach the fact it's pronounced with /e/ by more than half of North Americans, because that would be to teach "You need to distinguish between /æ/ and /e/, except before /r/", which would be an additional thing for the learners to remember.
